# How can I warn about function usage in `perl -c`?

Tags: perl, debugging, compiler-warnings

Our codebase includes various debugging hooks that should only be used for testing. As an illustrative example:

```perl
sub example {
   my ($arg) = @_;
   my $result = do_something_with($arg);
   debug_dump_values($arg); # debugging code
   return $result;
}
```

Of course, such debugging code should not be committed (or even deployed). Is there a way to generate a warning when running this code through `perl -c`? Something along the lines of

```
Debug function debug_dump_values() called at example.pl line 4.
```

This would be trivial to implement as a runtime warning:

```
sub debug_dump_values {
    carp "Debug function debug_dump_values() called";
    ...
}
```

But I want a warning that shows up in my text editor through its [syntax check plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic), so it needs to be a "compile-time" warning.

Comment: I would implement this as a pre-commit hook in your version control system.

Comment: That's a cool idea. If you have enough time to write an answer for it, I can put a green check mark next to it. ;)

Comment: What type of version control do you use? Maybe the question should be rephrased to something like, "How to prevent certain function calls from being committed in (Git|Subversion|Perforce)?"

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't an easy thing to accomplish - it's not going to be possible without some significant rejigging of coding style.

Approaches I can think of:

### Put your 'debug' code into a separate module.

Embed a warning in the module that indicates it's enabled - embed within a 'BEGIN' block. (This won't necessarily tell you which sub is being called though, nor where)

E.g.

```
BEGIN { 
    carp "Debugging module is imported" 
}
```

Advantages of this might be - you can have a 'debug' and 'not debug' module, and have the same subs in both. The 'not debug' would put in dummy subs.

You can then use [`B::Lint`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Lint.html) to validate your module and check if subs are all defined:

`perl -MO=Lint[,OPTIONS] foo.pl`

`undefined-subs
This option warns whenever an undefined subroutine is invoked. This option will only catch explicitly invoked subroutines such as foo() and not indirect invocations such as &$subref() or $obj->meth() . Note that some programs or modules delay definition of subs until runtime by means of the AUTOLOAD mechanism`

### Assign your sub via a reference.

Edit: Doesn't work as well as I thought - had a notion of declaring anonymous subs and creating references within 'BEGIN' blocks - that doesn't work as well as I thought - it only errors at runtime, because you get errors of scope.

Best I can offer is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

##debug code bit. 
#Comment out if not needed
my $debug_sub = gimme_debug();

sub gimme_debug {
    if ( $debug ) { 
        warn "Debugging enabled\n"; 
        return sub { print "Got values of :", @_, "\n"; };
    }
    else { warn "Debug subroutine defined with debug disabled!" };
}

#... way down code ... 

&$debug_sub ( "Some input" );
```

If you remove the declaration of then you'll get a compile time warning because `$debug_sub` is undeclared. This might combine with the above, e.g. bundling it in a module or object.

### Automated testing

It doesn't do specifically what you asked about, however you may want to consider it anyway. Automated testing for your code/modules. For example, using [`TAP::Harness`](http://perldoc.perl.org/TAP/Harness.html). It's a bit more complicated and intensive than what you're asking, but having something that'll automatically trap debug code (and otherwise validate the various components of your code) is probably the 'right' way to do it.

I've also heard of (but not done much with) [`Class::Inspector`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Class-Inspector-1.28/lib/Class/Inspector.pm) which may be suitable for your needs. 
But I think at a fairly fundamental level - what you're trying to do isn't checked at compile time, because it's very difficult to evaluate which bits of code are actually being called without actually running the code. So anything you do like this would be something you have to 'hand manage' in some fashion.

### [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

"In computability theory, the halting problem is the problem of determining, from a description of an arbitrary computer program and an input, whether the program will finish running or continue to run forever.

Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist. A key part of the proof was a mathematical definition of a computer and program, which became known as a Turing machine; the halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines. It is one of the first examples of a decision problem."

So if you do come up with a good solution to this - there's probably a usefully large prize on offer :).

Comment: re "Assign your sub via a reference" - are you sure this happens at compile time? Pretty sure this will be a run time error.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. That doesn't work. ER. I'll have another go.

Comment: Edited to something not quite as satisfactory, but that vaguely works.

Answer (score 0):

In my development environment, I face a similar problem. My approach has been to surround debugging code with C-style #ifdef and #endif comments, like this:

```
sub example {
   my ($arg) = @_;
   my $result = do_something_with($arg);
#ifdef DEBUG
   debug_dump_values($arg); # debugging code
#endif
   return $result;
}
```

As part of building a release, the program ppp.pl (that I wrote) runs on each Perl source file and comments out (or removes) the debugging code. A simple ppp.pl is easy to write. If anyone is interested, I can post my version in a public place.

Answer (score 0):

if you used Log::Log4perl  and create a logger called `$logger`, then you can check for debug mode via `$logger->is_debug()`  which will call the function only if debug level is enabled

your code could then just stay then, but only be called when debugging.

ie.

```
sub example {
   my ($arg) = @_;
   my $result = do_something_with($arg);
   debug_dump_values($arg) if $logger->is_debug(); # debugging code
   return $result;
}
```